# Make an hovering background have the link it's title has and change the hovering title

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, background, hover

So I'm facing a really big problem. I have an image that when hovered, a white box with a title appears. Now the title has a link to a page but not the box. I tried many thing (eg: applying "display:inline-block;" to the css (...)) but still no link was applyed. The point is for each box to have the same link has the title it contains. Also I can't seem to change the Title ("open") and the images have a lot of white space between them vertically. Anyone has any idea how to fix this?

Link to the page:

http://portugalweddingphotographer.com/portfolio/

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `a` tag wrap only the text, wrap upper divs tags, as:

```
<div class="section_hover">
    <a class="title_below_hover" href="http://portugalweddingphotographer.com/gallery/938/">
        <div style="display:inline-block;" class="grid_hover_div_padding">
            <div class="for_title_below the-title-hover">OPEN</div>
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
```